# Como eu faço um while sleep de 1 segundo apartir de um valor json? PHP

Tags: php, json, libcurl

Eai pessoal sou novo com PHP

eu fiz um CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:5112/resultado/?id='.$id.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, arraY('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; G011A) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'p.webshare.io:80');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'frbeibpp-rotate:j8ywaubloau6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$resultadodaconta = curl_exec($ch);
```

que manda a requisição para a API e me retorna em json o seguinte:

```
[ { "760ea20deb62c7906edae38c6f0b60e0": [ { "status": [ "Rodando" ] } ] } ]
```

eu quero que enquanto o status for Rodando eu quero que faça um `while` `sleep` de **1** segundo e quando o status mudar para concluído eu quero que ele exiba os resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, para você ler um json em php é com a função [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php), ela vai interpretar o json e te retornar um **objeto** ou **array**. Pra resolver esse teu exemplo, vou usar o retorno do json como array, pq achei a estrutura do json meio estranha, já que a chave é uma string aleatória.

Geralmente, se espera algo como:

```
{
   "token": "760ea20deb62c7906edae38c6f0b60e0"
}
```

Mas pra resolver esse seu problema vai na gambiarra mesmo, pois o json é objeto dentro de array e tals.

```
$json = json_decode('[ { "760ea20deb62c7906edae38c6f0b60e0": [ { "status": [ "Rodando" ] } ] } ]', true); // pega o json e converte pra um array

$token = array_keys($json[0]); // pega a chave do seu json de forma dinâmica, já que é uma string aleatoria

$status = $json[0][$token[0]][0]['status'][0]; // pega o status de acordo com a chave que foi obtida na linha acima

if($status == 'Rodando') {
    // while
    // sleep
    // sua lógica aew
}
```